# How do you create these illustrations in Illustrator that look like pencils by Ryan Putnam?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

[image]

I want to achieve the same style in Illustrator like the ones in here https://www.dropbox.com/pro

Comment: How about using a brush stroke?

Comment: That's how I'd do it, @David. You should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that guys. I figured it out. I tried bunch of different options but 'Warp Tool' seemed to be the closest.

**I used it with these settings:**
[image]

**Here are the results:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go about creating your shapes then applying the `Wrinkle Tool`:

[image]

If you double click the tool you get the options for the tool:

[image]

Create your shape:

[image]

Apply your settings in the panel and apply it to the stroke:

[image]

You will need to play with it but you can adjust your stroke and make the effect thicker, finer, or whatever you want:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I've tried this, but somehow I still feel its not the same.

Comment: @AbhijeetRaúlWankhade then why not include that in your question?  How long have you tried?  Have you practiced?  You're trying to mimic work from someone that has years using Illustrator.